# Setting bootstrap nav breakpoint to show mobile nav on ipad portrait

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Having trouble setting the breakpoint for bootstrap nav and sub-nav on iPad portrait and down. I need the navigation to show the mobile version on iPad portrait and iPhone portrait and landscape, but currently stuck with it showing desktop sub-nav on iPad portrait:

[image]

So it should appear like this on iPad portrait:

[image]

It works in the fiddle here: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/0hLfwvsh/1/), though the collapse doesn't happen until 768px. I can't get it to work, however, in my code.

**HTML:**

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default profile-btn">Profile</button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT US <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WHAT WE DO<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="col-sm-4 image-column">
              <ul>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Link & Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link & Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-sm-4">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">long link title</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Really long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link title here</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">OUR RESULTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

header .header-brand {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

header .header-brand:focus,
header .header-brand:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5e5e5e;
}

.navbar .btn.profile-btn,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:hover,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:focus {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  min-width: 800px;
}

@media (max-width: 967px) {
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  .icon-bar{
     background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

Comment: when do you want it break? 967?

Comment: @muratkh - it should break at 967 so that the mobile version of the main nav and subnav only show on iPad portrait and iPhone portrait/landscape.

Answer (score 0):

WHAT I DID, I DIDN'T KNOW YOU WERE USING 4 COLUMNS NO MATTER WHAT SO I CHANGED THEM LG 4 XS 12 CHANGED THE MINWIDTH TO 750

HTML

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-nav" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default profile-btn">Profile</button>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-nav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">ABOUT US <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">WHAT WE DO<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 image-column">
              <ul>

                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/156x120" class="img-responsive" alt=""></a>
                    <h4 class="picture-sub">LINK</h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Link & Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link & Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="col-md-4 col-xs-12">
              <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">long link title</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Really long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Longer link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link title here</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header spacer">LINK</li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Long link title</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">OUR RESULTS <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINK</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">NEWS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">LOCATIONS</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">CONTACT</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
 header {
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
}

header .header-brand {
  color: #777;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
}

header .header-brand:focus,
header .header-brand:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #5e5e5e;
}

.navbar .btn.profile-btn,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:hover,
.navbar .btn.profile-btn:focus {
  float: right;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}

.mega-dropdown-menu {
  min-width:750px;
}

@media (max-width: 967px) {
  .navbar .navbar-toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  }
@media (max-width: 967px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
   .mega-dropdown-menu ul{
     display: block;
     position: relative;
}
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin: 7.5px -15px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .navbar-text {
        float: none;
        margin: 15px 0;
    }
    /* since 3.1.0 */
    .navbar-collapse.collapse.in { 
        display: block!important;
    }
    .collapsing {
        overflow: hidden!important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, the subnav is showing up correctly on mobile, but on tablet portrait its still showing up as it does on desktop.

Comment: THAT'S cause you gotta add a display: block for your mega-dropdown-menu inside the breakpoint.

Comment: or change the width

Comment: Setting `.mega-dropdpown-menu{display:block}` only allows it to show up. I need it to display as a list like it does on iphone portrait.

Comment: i got it i got it try now

Comment: i reset the min-width: to 100%

Comment: That's just centering the subnav. Take a look at the screenshot I provided in the question of how it looks on iphone. That's how it needs to appear on portrait ipad. Also, this applies to all subnav, not just the big mega dropdown one.

Comment: TRY NOW IF THIS DOESNT WORK KILL ME

Comment: muratkh, do you have a fiddle you've tested this code in? I'm not seeing the fix when I apply it to my code. (don't kill yourself :))

Comment: Ah hah! Thanks for cracking away at this. It's working now. However, its still acting like the desktop version of the subnav, where the subnav shows over the other parent nav links instead of below the current parent nav link. Does that make sense?

Comment: yea i see it happens before the second breakpoint it takes from position absolute to relative probably.

Comment: Yeah, trying to figure out how to set it so that all subnavs display with the desktop version of the dropdown only on desktop and not on ipad portrait or iphone both orientations.

Comment: try this approach, get rid of your navbar start from scratch, normally default navbar is not working like this at all after a breakpoint give your classes other names than you're using now, see if that solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the solution was to set a new breakpoint:

```
@media (max-width: 800px){
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
     float: none; 
     width: auto;
     margin-top: 0;
     background-color: transparent;
     border: 0;
     -webkit-box-shadow: none;
     box-shadow: none;
 }
}
```

which brings the sub-nav on iPad portrait to the same as iPhone portrait.

[image]